# Why $\|S\|=\sup_{\|x\| \leq 1}\|Sx\|?$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{B}(F)$ the algebra of all bounded linear operators on a complex Hilbert space $F$. It is well known that if $S\in \mathcal{B}(F)$, then 
$$\|S\|:=\sup_{\substack{x\in F\\ x\not=0}}\frac{\|Sx\|}{\|x\|}$$

Why
$$\|S\|=\sup_{\|x\| \leq 1}\|Sx\|?$$

Comment: Show they are both equivalent to $ \sup_{||x||=1} ||Sx||$. Hint: Use the linearity of S. The solution isn't enlightening, its more important you understand why you can restrict to the unit sphere.

Comment: @LukePeachey Thank you. Is what I write true $$\|S\|:=\sup_{\substack{x\in F\\ x\not=0}}\left\|S(\frac{x}{\|x\|})\right\|=\sup_{\|x\| =1}\|Sx\|?$$

Comment: Yes its correct. There are quite a few equivalent definitions of the operator norm like this, just get comfortable using them all and make sure you understand why it only depends on the sphere.

Comment: @LukePeachey Thank you very much. Why it only depends on the sphere?

Comment: Notice that $\frac{||S(x)||}{||x||}$ is constant on a line passing through the origin. Therefore this function is completely determind by its values on any central sphere, in particular the unit sphere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very standard [exercise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm#Equivalent_definitions) in functional analysis. One can show
$$
A:=\sup_{\substack{x\in F\\ x\not=0}}\frac{\|Sx\|}{\|x\|}=\sup_{\|x\| \leq 1}\|Sx\|=:B
$$
by showing $A\leq B$ and $A\geq B$. One direction is almost trivial.

- Note that $\left\|\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right\|=1$ for $x\neq 0$ and observe that the norm is by definition *absolutely homogeneous*: $\|ax\|=|a|\|x\|$. Show that $A\leq B$.
- To show $A\geq B$, it suffices to show that $A\geq \|Sx\|$ for all $\|x\|\leq 1$. There are two cases.

  - If $x=0$, then this is trivially true.
  - If $0<\|x\|\leq 1$, then $\frac{\|Sx\|}{\|x\|}\geq\|Sx\|$ implies that $A\geq \|Sx\|$.

<sup>(The proof above is also true when $F$ is only a Banach space.)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't understand very well why $A\leq B$

Comment: @Thierry: Note that by homogeneity of the norm, $\{\frac{\|Sx\|}{\|x\|}:x\neq 0\}$ is the same as $\{\|Sx\|:\|x\|=1|\}$, which is a *subset* of $\{\|Sx\|:\|x\leq1|\}$.

Comment: Thank you, now it is very clear.